# Codebase for making a Flash-based interactive map with SVG vector data?

Tags: flash, actionscript, svg, vector-graphics

I'm looking for a way to take SVG path info (basically a string of coordinates) and dynamically draw it with Actionscript.  Icing on the cake would be if those shapes could detect mouse events to trigger JS and dynamically change their appearance (fill, stroke, etc...).

I'm currently trying something similar to this (http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html) using SVG but it's just too slow in IE.  I've also tried Google's SVG Web (http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) which basically does exactly what I'm looking for (it converts SVG to Flash in IE) but again, it's sloooooow - which is why I'm considering doing the whole shebang in Flash.

Anyone know of some links to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [SVG Viewer](http://labs.zavoo.com/?cat=10) from zavoo labs. It's hosted in google code, so I guess you can freely modify it. The `SVGPath` class is where parsing and drawing of `path` elements happens - you can grab that code and modify it to your requirements.